# Geometric warping showing black image

Tags: c++, opencv, transformation, perspective, homography

I am having an issue with geometric warping, basically warping an image in the perspective of a top down view. Without using points.

**What I have:**

1. I have an image looking at a 45deg angle (i.e) F is the location of my camera pointing down
   [image]
2. [This](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp04/cse252b/notes/lec04/lec4.pdf) paper on what I want to do. Page 2 has the main formula
3. Main function used in opencv `cv::warpPerspective` to active this warped image
4. I have the necessary Ccam1_cam2 roation (assuming my math is correct)

**What I have done:**

1. I have generate an H matrix using the formula from the paper.
2. Tested if there was no translation only a rotation i.e `H=R` if that would make the warped image look any better.
3. Looked at my x,y values from the warped image and notice that they are <1 which is bad because they need to be in the range of 400x530 which is the original image.

   Code:

   ```
   cv::Mat  hmatrix = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,3) << H.c11, H.c12, H.c13, 
                          H.c21, H.c22, H.c23, 
                          H.c31, H.c32, H.c33);
   lfImg = cv::imread("undistortedsmall.bmp", 0);
   imshow("not warped image", lfImg);
   cv::waitKey(0);
   cv::Mat warpedimg;
   cv::Scalar borderValue;
   cv::warpPerspective(lfImg, warpedimg, hmatrix ,lfImg.size(),cv::INTER_LINEAR,cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,borderValue);

   imshow("warpedImage", warpedimg);
   ```
4. I have taken points from a top down image with the corresponding points from my 45deg image and generated a H matrix that warps well. Just to see what the H matrix could look like. But the scale is completely different.

example:

```
 My generated H Matrix:
      0.240053 0.859119 -0.451983
      0.689905 -0.478534 -0.543171
      -0.682938 -0.181435 -0.707585

 pt generated H matrix
     0.894764 3.37653 77.6052
     -0.950235 2.02846 240.977
     -8.73899e-05 0.00384326 1
```

**What I want:**

A Top down warping of the that image without using points extracted from the image.

**The Problem** 
    Black screen (if I scale the matrix my some multiple lets say *100)
    I get an incorrect warping but at least something that is visable

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown full code that generates values in H - it is hard to say for sure, but you may be missing an intrinsic parameters matrix (also often referred as camera calibration matrix).

It is not mentioned in the paper you have provided, which means they work with so called 'normalized' or 'uncalibrated' homography. When you generate a homography from point corresponedences you obtain a 'calibrated' homography and get expected results.

Consider section **3D plane to plane equation** [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography_%28computer_vision%29). As you can see R-(t*n^t)/d is premultiplied by matrix Ka and postmultiplied by Kb^-1(inverted second camera's intrinsic matrix), in order to produce a 'calibrated' homography. If both images are taken with a same camera you can assume Ka = Kb.

So, in order to obtain 'calibrated' homography you can use expression Hc = K * H * K^-1, where Hc is calibrated homography, H is uncalibrated homography, and K is calibration matrix.

Now, you need to extimate K. Ideally you should perform camera calibration in order to get it, but if you know camera's focal length you can use a somewhat rough approximation as follows:

```
    | f, 0, cx |
K = | 0, f, cy |
    | 0, 0,  1 |
```

where f is camera's focal length in pixel units, and (cx, cy) are the coordinates of principal point (you can use (w/2, h/2) where w and h are image's width and height in pixels)